# How to write datafame specific functions in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to write a function that operates on specific elements of a data frame.  For instance, in the way that filter uses a data frame, followed by the specific elements, I want to use this same type of assignment in my own function.

I am using this to edit baseball data, for one example I want to write a function that is able to calculate on base percentage with the information in a specific row.

```
onbase <- function(df, H, BB, HBP, AB, SF) {

  OBP <- (H + BB + HBP)/(AB + BB + HBP + SF)

  return(OBP)
}
```

This is what I have come up with so far, but I have been unable to subset this for a specific data frame. Is there a way to specify in the function structure that a specific input comes from within a working dataframe?

I also would want to write it into the data frame as a new column, but so far I've only been able to return the vector OBP and write that in separately.

How might I go about solving this?

Comment: All you need to do is pass `df` to your function, and prefix all those variables inside the function with `df` (i.e., `df$OBP <- (df$H + ...`). Then just return the entire data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr and rlang:

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
d <- data.frame(H = sample(1:100, 10),
                BB = sample(1:100, 10),
                HBP = sample(1:100, 10),
                AB = sample(1:100, 10),
                SF = sample(1:100, 10))

onbase <- function(df, H, BB, HBP, AB, SF) {
  H <- enquo(H)
  BB <- enquo(BB)
  HBP <- enquo(HBP)
  AB <- enquo(AB)
  SF <- enquo(SF)
  out <- mutate(df, OBP := (!!H + !!BB + !!HBP)/(!!AB + !!BB + !!HBP + !!SF))
  return(out)
}

onbase(d, H, BB, HBP, AB, SF)
#>     H BB HBP AB  SF       OBP
#> 1  41 32  82 50  42 0.7524272
#> 2  71 75  66 92  16 0.8514056
#> 3  70 60  41 98  77 0.6195652
#> 4  45 90  29 16  59 0.8453608
#> 5  93 74  98 85  41 0.8892617
#> 6   1 10  89 38  52 0.5291005
#> 7   5 47  30 90  56 0.3677130
#> 8  15  7  55 17  32 0.6936937
#> 9  58 77  45 42 100 0.6818182
#> 10 64  9  85 78  27 0.7939698
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I don't know baseball statistics, so I just made up numbers, but the calculation works.